# Access controls from a normal class (.cs)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-controls

I'm working on a project and need to access a label from a normal class.cs.
NOT from the MainWindow.xaml.cs!

`MainWindow.xaml`: contains a Label `lblTag`.

Class.cs needs to execute:

```
lblTag.Content = "Content";
```

How can I realize it?

I just end up with **`InvalidOperationExceptions`**.

Window1.xaml.cs:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    [...]
}

[...]
StreamElement se1;
StreamElement se2;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    [...]
    se1 = new StreamElement(this);
    se2 = new StreamElement(this);

    [...]
}

[...]
```

StreamElement.cs:

```
[...]
private Window1 _window;
[...]

public StreamElement(Window1 window)
{
    _window = window;
}

[...]

//metaSync is called, whenever the station (it's a sort of internet radio recorder)
//changes the meta data
public void metaSync(int handle, int channle, int data, IntPtr user)
{
    [...]

    //Tags just gets the meta data from the file stream
    Tags t = new Tags(_url, _stream);
    t.getTags();

    //throws InvalidOperationException - Already used in another thread
    //_window.lblTag.Content = "Content" + t.title;
}

[...]
```

Comment: Give your control a name, e.g. `<Label x:Name="myLabel" .../>`

Comment: won't lblTag.Content = "String"; be enough?

Comment: If the control is *named* lblTag then you should be able to just use "lblTag.Content" (without quotes).  Try typing "this." and see what Intellisense tells you about the controls on the XAML

Comment: I want to access the control from a simple .cs file. not the MainWindow.xaml.cs ;D

Comment: What is the exact message of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to an instance of MainWindow class in your Class:

```
public Class
{
    private MainWindow window;

    public Class(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        window = mainWindow;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        window.lblTag.Content = "Content";
    }
}
```

You need to pass a reference to your window instance to the class. From inside your MainWindow window code behind you would call:

```
var c = new Class(this);
c.MyMethod();
```

EDIT:

You can only access controls from the same thread. If your class is running in another thread you need to use the Dispatcher:

```
public void metaSync(int handle, int channle, int data, IntPtr user)
{
    [...]

    //Tags just gets the meta data from the file stream
    Tags t = new Tags(_url, _stream);
    t.getTags();

    //throws InvalidOperationException - Already used in another thread
    //_window.lblTag.Content = "Content" + t.title;

    _window.lblTag.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _window.lblTag.Content = "Content" + t.title;
            }));
}
```

Comment: @dr0n3: probably because you haven't set the window variable.

Comment: @dr0n3 You need to initialize the variable first. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @dr0n3 In the updated question you said it was InvalidOperationException. I updated the answer with info on how to call UI code from a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

after the edit, this seems clearer now. Damir's answer should be correct.

Just add a mainwindow object on Class.cs and pass the mainwindow's instance to the class's constructor.

on mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
...
Class class = new Class(this);
...
```

on Class.cs

```
...
MainWindow mWindow = null;

// constructor
public Class(MainWindow window)
{
   mWindow = window;
}

private void Initialize()
{
   window.lblTag.Content = "whateverobject";
}
```

Comment: That just throws an InvalidOperationException telling me that this object is already used in another thread.

Comment: odd. could you share how you're passing the reference of the mainwindow to the class? and how you're using the class object?